# Single column of data into multiple columns single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has one column. How do I write a T-SQL statement to return all the rows in the table as one row but a column for each row of data in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by building a dynamic sql statement.

```
-- Test data
declare @T table (F varchar(10))
insert into @T values
('Row 1'),
('Row 2'),
('Row 3'),
('Row 4'),
('Row 5')

-- String to hold dynamic sql
declare @S as varchar(max)
set @S = 'select '

--Build string
select @S = @S + quotename(F, '''') + ',' 
from @T
set @S = left(@S, len(@s)-1)

--Execute sql 
exec (@S)
```

Result

```
----- ----- ----- ----- -----
Row 1 Row 2 Row 3 Row 4 Row 5
```

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for a pivot : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Comment: Actually, PIVOT doesn't do what the op asked for. It would get the column **names** as the values of his table, not the value of the new columns.